# Best way to delete Activity and its references in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I created an activity by accident (let's call it FooActivity) in Android Studio. What is the best way to delete this and all associated references/code? What I did was I deleted FooActivity.java, res/layout/activity_foo.xml, and the associated  tag in AndroidManifest.xml. But I'm not sure if I'm missing anything else associated with FooActivity. Ideally, it would be nice to be able to do all of this automatically when I no longer need a given activity.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm answering my own question since I figured out a way to see exactly what got added after creating a new activity.

Since I was putting everything under Git version control, I realized that I could do a git diff with a fake activity to see exactly what the changes were. I discovered that the following files are added whenever a new activity is created:

```
FooActivity.java
app/src/main/res/layout/activity_foo.xml
app/src/main/res/menu/foo.xml
```

In AndroidManifest.xml, the following is added:

```
<activity
    android:name=".FooActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_foo" >
</activity>
```

In app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml, the following is added:

```
<string name="title_activity_foo">FooActivity</string>
```

Of course, this wouldn't catch other references that were added after creating the new activity, so EyesClear's and Shahzad's answers would allow you to find these references. But in the future, I would probably checkout a new branch before creating a new activity so that I could nuke any changes that I don't like.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think automatic references **removal** is possible, but you can use the *safe delete* feature (right click on the activity -> delete -> check the *safe delete* option) to **find** all references in code and comments. Anyway, if a reference points to non-existing class, your project won't compile and an error will be shown with detailed information, so you'll be able to solve it quickly.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on windows press `Ctrl+Shift+F` or `Command+Shift+F` for Mac to open the Find in Path dialog and enter FooActivity. This should show you all occurrences of FooActivity.

Answer (score 2):

Just right click on activity which you want to delete -> Delete->Ok->Delete Anyway[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was working on deleting an Activity and found a way.

You can right click on an activity->Find Usages(Alt+F7).

You will get a list of files where the activity is used in the project,  and then delete.

Answer (score 0):

To remove all reference and associated files of the `FooActivity`, I would press `Control+Z` just after the `Activity` creation,It'll then ask you to confirm the action. So that all the references and associated files would get deleted without any trouble.